# Which module choose for file upload in NodeJs from Multer and Fileupload?

Tags: node.js

I am new to NodeJs. I found two module to upload file on server i.e, [Multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) and [FileUpload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fileupload). But i confuse to choose one. Can anyone explain what is difference between them and which is best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multer is good plugin for file upload but if you want fast and large file uploading then i suggest that use https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable